# Binding value as ConverterParameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

In my resourceDictionary I have a following style:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type propgrid:PropertyGridDataAccessorItem}" x:Key="{x:Type propgrid:PropertyGridDataAccessorItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="DataAccessorType" Value="Category">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding DisplayName, Converter={local:ExpandedCategoryConverter}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

I need to bind a value from my viewModel to ConverterParameter, something like ConverterParameter = {Binding MyProperty}, but we can't bind to a ConverterParameter.

How can I solve this issue?

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have discovered, you cannot bind `ConverterParameter` because it's not a dependency property.

Most of the time the solution for this is to simply use a `MultiBinding` and a [multi value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) instead, for example:

```
<Trigger Property="DataAccessorType" Value="Category">
  <Setter Property="IsExpanded">
    <Setter.Value>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{local:ExpandedCategoryConverter}">
        <Binding Path="DisplayName"/>
        <Binding Path="WhatYouWantToPassInAsConverterParameter"/>
      </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

The converter would of course need to be updated appropriately.

Comment: Just one more question - when I set binding <Binding PropertyName/>, I get errors "Expected an attribute value. Attribute values are delimited by a single quotation makr or a double quotation mark"
and "The property '' was not found in type #Binding'". How can I handle this?

Comment: @Sasha: `<Binding Path="PropertyName" />`.